# Embedding an SVG as std::string in C++ source code

Tags: c++, svg

I finally moved away from the bitmaps and trying to use SVG in my C++ code.

I made an SVG using [Inkscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape) and saved it as *Compressed*.

Then I edited the resulting file by adding the

```
static const char data[] =
```

in front of the XML and place every single line of XML inside double quotes.

The resulting file then is saved as .h file and included in the C++ source code.

However, when compiling I am getting the following:

```
error: stray ‘#’ in program
   13 | " <g stroke="#000">"
      |              ^
```

What can I do? Linux does not have a notion of resources and I'd rather embed the graphics, than allow an external file.

Below is the beginning of the header file in question:

`
static const char query[] =

""

""

" "

"  rdf:RDF"

"   <cc:Work rdf:about="">"

"    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>"

"    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>"

"    <dc:title/>"

"   </cc:Work>"

"  </rdf:RDF>"

" "

" "

"  "

"   "
`

Comment: Do you understand the reason for the error? Do you know understand the solution, for classical C++? A recent revision to the C++ standard does allow for a fairly simple adjustment to make it easy to do something like this, but it is also important for you to understand what happened here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, the `#` indicates that it is a pre-processor directive and so the preceding double quote needs to be prepended with the backslash. But I was hoping to have an easier solution, since I have to do that more than 1 time in 1 svg... And I will have more than 1 file. Also, are yo talking about C++20 there?

Comment: This is correct. Any quotes and backslashes in quoted strings must themselves be backslashed. A simple script that reads the SVG file and prepends the backslashes will do the trick. It shouldn't take more than a minute or two to write such a script. or raw string literals can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want a raw string literal introduced in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11).

```
static const char data[] = R"xxx(<?xml version="1.0"...)xxx";
```

This is equivalent to

```
static const char data[] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"...";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's still fashionable, but a well known technique is to use a program called a *Resource Compiler* which can accept the file you give it and transform it into the encoded textual form that can be embedded into the code. Often these will produce a header file that creates a `char[]` object in the form described in Peng's answer.

For a very quick and very dirty example, here's a complete shell session creating and running a simple resource compiler. More sophisticated RC programs can produce more readable strings.

```
$ cat > res.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "static const char $1[] = \""
od -An -b -v -w1 $2 | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=""; ORS=""} { print "\\" $1 }'
echo "\";";
#<-- press ^D here
$ chmod +x res.sh
$ ./res.sh resource_compiler res.sh > res.h
$ cat res.h
static const char resource_compiler[] = "\043\041\057\0142\0151\0156\057\0163\0150\012\0145\0143\0150\0157\040\055\0156\040\042\0163\0164\0141\0164\0151\0143\040\0143\0157\0156\0163\0164\040\0143\0150\0141\0162\040\044\061\0133\0135\040\075\040\0134\042\042\012\0157\0144\040\055\0101\0156\040\055\0142\040\055\0166\040\055\0167\061\040\044\062\040\0174\0134\012\040\040\040\0141\0167\0153\040\047\0102\0105\0107\0111\0116\0173\0117\0106\0123\075\042\042\073\040\0117\0122\0123\075\042\042\0175\040\057\0136\040\060\057\0173\040\0160\0162\0151\0156\0164\040\042\0134\0134\042\040\044\061\040\0175\040\057\0136\040\061\057\0173\040\0160\0162\0151\0156\0164\040\042\0134\0134\060\042\040\044\061\040\0175\047\012\0145\0143\0150\0157\040\042\0134\042\073\042\073\012";
```

Or, here's a C program which does the same thing.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
  if(  argc != 3  ){
    fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s <variable-name> <file-name>\n"
                    "Read named file and produce C program text "
                      "constructing a string variable containing file.", argv[0] );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }
  FILE *f = fopen( argv[2], "rb" );
  if(!  f  ){
    fprintf( stderr, "Error: unable to open filename %s\n%s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno) );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }
  printf( "static const char %s[] = \"", argv[1] );
  int byte;
  while(  (byte = fgetc( f )) != EOF  )
      printf( "\\%03o", byte );
  printf( "\";\n" );
}
```

In action:

```
$ make rc
cc     rc.c   -o rc
$ ./rc var rc.sh
static const char var[] = "\043\041\057\142\151\156\057\163\150\012\145\143\150\157\040\055\156\040\042\163\164\141\164\151\143\040\143\157\156\163\164\040\143\150\141\162\040\044\061\133\135\040\075\040\134\042\042\012\157\144\040\055\101\156\040\055\142\040\055\166\040\055\167\061\040\044\062\040\174\040\141\167\153\040\047\102\105\107\111\116\173\117\106\123\075\042\042\073\040\117\122\123\075\042\042\175\040\173\040\160\162\151\156\164\040\042\134\134\042\040\044\061\040\175\047\012\145\143\150\157\040\042\134\042\073\042\073\012";
$ ./rc var var
Error: unable to open filename var
No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? E.g., with some actual code/tests/command line invocations and/or install instructions, and/or platform information. For instance, enough information to be able to reproduce it on a particular platform. It sounds very Windows'y or Macintosh'y. Is it? (But *** *** *** *** *** ***without*** *** *** *** *** ***  "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @PeterMortensen There ya go! :)